# How to avoid duplicate input on stdin when using 2-process pipeline with stdin and stdout redirect

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, ipc

I am intending to set up a pipeline between two processes: parent and child. The parent forks the child and uses execve to replace its image with that of a specified process.

The parent reads from stdin via std::getline(std::cin, input_line).
The child writes to the stdout via std::cout << output_line.

I am looking to setup a pipe and redirect the output of the child to the input of the parent.

The problem is that the parent receives each input (where each input is a number output by the child on stdout) twice. I would like to fix this issue but I don't understand why it is happening.

Code is compiled with g++ 7.4.0 and C++11 standard version.

Child is compiled to a binary called 'p1'.

Parent code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <sys/wait.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <iostream>

char *
  const p1argv[] = {
    (char * )
    "./p1",
    nullptr
  };
char *
  const p1envp[] = {
    (char * ) nullptr
  };

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

  pid_t p1id;
  int p1fd[2];

  pipe(p1fd);
  if (p1id = fork() == 0) {

    close(p1fd[0]);
    dup2(p1fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

    execve(argv[0], p1argv, p1envp);
    perror("Error: failed to execve ./p1.");

  } else {

    dup2(p1fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(p1fd[1]);

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
      std::cout << "d(" << line << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    int status;
    waitpid(p1id, & status, 0);

    close(p1fd[0]);
  }
}
```

Child code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    long it = 0;
    while(true) {
        it += 1;
        std::cout << std::to_string(it) << std::endl; 
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    }
}
```

The actual output for the sample code is:

d(d(1))
d(d(2))
...

The expected output is:

d(1)
d(2)
...

Comment: might not solve your problem but `p1id = fork() == 0` is suspect. `p1id` will always be 0 or 1 since `fork() == 0` is evaluated first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this line:

```
 execve(argv[0], p1argv, p1envp);
```

Is re-executing the main parent program, because that is what the content of `argv[0]` is at this point.  I think you want to find some way to specify `"./p1"` there.